# Нужно написать программу, которая считывала количество символов в каждом введенном слове

Tags: c++

```
> #include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
// программа считает только количество слов в строке
// и считает общее количество символов и вместе с пробелами
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    char str[80];
    int word, count = 0;
    cout << "Введите строку: " << endl;
    cin.get(str, 80);
    int i = 0;
    while (str[i] == ' ' && str[i] != '\0')
    {
        i++;
    }
        word = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (str[i] != ' ' && word == 0)
        {
            word = 1;
            count++;
        }
        else if (str[i] == ' ')
        {
            word = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }
    cout << "Количество слов в строке " << count;
    cout << endl;

    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        i++;
    }
    cout << i;
    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Добавьте счетчик. Началось слово - вы же слова считать умеете! - счетчик запустился. Закончилось - вот и получилось количество символов...

Comment: Я данный код в интернете нашел)))) пытаюсь разобраться)

Comment: Считаю, что не нужно отказать новому участнику...

Answer (score 2):

```
const size_t lenght = strlen(str);
char* q = new char[lenght + 1];
strcpy(q, str);
char*p = strtok(q, " ");
size_t counter = 0;
while(p) {
    ++counter;
    cout  << p << " __ символов: " << strlen(p) << endl;
    p = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
delete []q;
cout << "\nколичество слов:  " << counter;
```

Нужно просто использовать то, что уже написано.  `strtok` какраз разделяет массив символов на лексемы...

Comment: Вы о чем? Я всего лишь убрал из вашего ответа лишний комментарий. Вы на ruSO достаточно давно, чтобы понимать, что это база знаний, вики, а не форум.

Comment: Касательно вопроса - "Надо написать А, вот мой код, разбирайтесь" - вполне достойно и минуса и закрытия.

Comment: К сожалению даже так, от такого комментария нет пользы. То что вы разместили ответ - вы молодец.